# Why object's address changes each time in r

Tags: r, list, object

I execute following commands in rstudio and I get each time different address (for part of object).  Can you help me?

thanks

```
require(lobstr)
x <- list(1, 2, 3)
ref(x[1])
```

Comment: x[1] mean again a list, x[[1]] is the content of list at first index. so question is the address was changed?

Comment: it is because this is a list and each element is in a different location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`list`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/list)

> Lists are copied element-by-element into a pairlist and the names of the list used as tags for the pairlist: the return value for other types of argument is undocumented.

As these are element-by-element `copy`, the address is different.  Inorder to understand, just create a `NULL` list of some `length`.  Initially, all of them have the same address, but once the values are assigned, it gets copied and thus the address changes

```
library(lobstr)
x1 <- vector('list', 3)
sapply(x1, ref)
#[1] "[1:0x7fc1e00746e0] <NULL>" "[1:0x7fc1e00746e0] <NULL>" "[1:0x7fc1e00746e0] <NULL>"
```

All of the above show same location.  Now, we assign values one by one and note the change in address

```
x1[[1]] <- 1
sapply(x1, ref)
#[1] "[1:0x7fc162dc10f0] <dbl>"  "[1:0x7fc1e00746e0] <NULL>" "[1:0x7fc1e00746e0] <NULL>"
x1[[2]] <- 2
sapply(x1, ref)
#[1] "[1:0x7fc162dc10f0] <dbl>"  "[1:0x7fc1608c86a8] <dbl>"  "[1:0x7fc1e00746e0] <NULL>"
```

Comment: thanks. I mean when I re execute only  ref(x[1]), the address results changing ! 

require(lobstr)
x <- list(1, 2, 3)

ref(x[1])
ref(x[1])
ref(x[1])

Comment: @tahzibi it is doing a copy.  I updated the post to show exactly how it is happening

Comment: akrun, thanks. but did u see my comment? require(lobstr) x <- list(1, 2, 3) ref(x[1]) ref(x[1]) ref(x[1])

Comment: @tahzibi that is because you are still doing the `ref` on the `list` i.e. `ref(x[1]`) instead of `ref(x[[1]])`.  Try this multiple ties and it is the same address. i..e `x[1]` is a list and not a vector

Comment: As we are returning a list, it is a copy `@ address(x[1])
[1] "0x7fc1814ced58"
> address(x[1])
[1] "0x7fc1814cec08"
> address(x[1])
[1] "0x7fc1814e9190"
and not when ` address(x[[1]])
[1] "0x7fc1760d24d0"
> address(x[[1]])
[1] "0x7fc1760d24d0"`